# How do I prevent Windows (10) from accessing my storage drive during boot?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have a SSD with the OS and all executables and settings and such on it as my primary drive, and then I have a HDD strictly used for storing infrequently accessed data files.

When I unplug the storage drive, the computer boots up in about 13 seconds. But when it's attached it takes about 22 seconds to boot. This is annoying since there's nothing on there that Windows needs to be looking at while booting up. How can I fix this?

It is possible that it's the BIOS accessing the drive, but it doesn't spin up until 8 seconds in, so I'm assuming it's Windows.

Comment: Do you unplug the storage drive before or after shutting down Windows. I ask because I've noticed that my laptop takes longer to boot up if I haven't unused any mapped drives before the previous shutdown and the network's disconnected (ie the previously mapped drives are unavailable).  Perhaps this is something similar.

Comment: always while it's off. (it's inside the case, connected to the motherboard and psu)

Comment: Could it be an antivirus performing a quick scan? Test by excluding the drive from AV.

Comment: Change the boot order and place that storage drive at last.